# What is the line perpendicular to $y=3x-1$ that passes through the $x$-axis at $4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is perpendicular so $m$ must be $\frac{-1}{3}$, and so to find the $y$-intercept you substitute in $4$ for $x$ in $y=\frac{-1}{3}\cdot x$, and solving this got me $\frac{-4}{3}$. But when I put $y=\frac{-1}{3}x-\frac{4}{3}$ I got an $x$-intercept of $-4$, not $4$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Your $m$ is correct. Now let find intercept $c$. Our perpendicular line is $y=m\cdot x + c$, and it passing the point $A=(4,0)$, so the coordinates of point $A$ have to satisfy the equation $y=m\cdot x + c$.

That is why we have:
$$0=\frac{-1}{3}\cdot4+c \iff c=\frac{4}{3}.$$

Thus, our perpendicular line is:
$$y=\frac{-1}{3} \cdot x+\frac{4}{3}.$$

Figure.
[image]

Comment: Thank, this worked! I was only substituting in x and trying to solve for y, instead of putting in both and solving for c. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

You know the gradient $m$ and you should use the intercept to find $c$ (I take it you are using $y=mx+c$)

Recall that changing $c$ translates the line without changing its direction, so it will remain perpendicular to the original provided $m$ is fixed.